# Weird use of generics

Tags: c#, generics

After a bit of programming one of my classes used generics in a way I never seen before. I would like some opinions of this, if it's bad coding or not.

```
abstract class Base<T> : where T : Base<T>
{
    // omitted methods and properties.
    virtual void CopyTo(T instance) { /*code*/ }
}

class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    override void CopyTo(Derived instance)
    { 
         base.CopyTo(instance);
         // copy remaining stuff here
    }
}
```

is this  an OK use of generics or not? I'm mostly thinking about the constraint to "itself". I sometimes feel like generics can "explode" to other classes where I use the Base class.

Comment: Actually it's not really uncommon, I've seen it before...

Comment: That's what Generics are for. I would probably expose an interface though to make it even more abstract.

Comment: Why do you need the type T to be a Base<T>? I didn't see any reason for that in your sample, actually I can't figure out why you are using that, is anything I'm missing?

Comment: @Carlos, It means that T must derive from Base<T> therefore X : Base<X> would be true where X : Base<Y> wouldn't.

Comment: @Filip I see that, i don't see a good reason for it. My comment was more related about the intent behind this code. May you provide some real examples where it is useful for doing it?

Comment: @Carlos, as Jon answered, you might not always want to expose the generic types in your API. Sometimes it makes more sense to use X instead of Y<T>.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is the C++ "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is reasonable - I have something similar in my Protocol Buffers port (except more complicated, as there are two mutually referenced types).

You're absolutely right about generics sometimes ending up spreading across the code-base - what you've done here means that bits of code which only care about `Derived` having an appropriate API don't need to worry about the generics.

My advice is to try to keep it simple where possible, but in cases where an "odd" generic constraint really does describe what you want, go for it. You should be aware that this doesn't *force* valid use though - you could easily have:

```
class Banana : Base<Derived>
```

and that would be valid, though odd and probably unexpected to users.

You might also want to consider sealing `Derived` here - if you derive further, you're again likely to end up with odd behavior (or at least an odd API).

Comment: Jon, wouldn't Banana : Base<Derived> fail? Since `where T : Base<T>`?

Comment: @Filip Ekberg, no, it works, since T = `Derived`, and `Derived` is a `Base<Derived>`

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's a fine line of having generics all over the consuming code and having class bloats with lots of classes. In my case there is specific code in the derived classes so it makes sense for me.

I will take up on your advice regarding sealed. It fits nicely in my scenario. Thanks